# Is that word Feminine or Masculine?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, regular-expression

Write a program or function that takes in a single string containing only lowercase a-z, and prints or returns a **[truthy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/26997)** value if the word is the **feminine** version of the thing it represents and a **[falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/26997)** value if it is the **masculine** version. For example, `hen` is the feminine version for chicken and `rooster` is the masculine version, so `hen` might produce `1` and `rooster` might produce `0`.

Doing this for *all* English words that reflect gender would of course be way too unwieldy. Your program/function only needs to support 20 masculine/feminine pairs. Below are five sets of 10 masculine/feminine pairs, categorized by topic. **Choose any two of the sets; the 20 total pairs in these two sets are the 40 words your program/function must work for.**

(format is `masculine_version feminine_version`)

1. General

   ```
   he she
   him her
   man woman
   boy girl
   male female
   masculine feminine
   guy gal
   lad lass
   mister miss
   sir madam
   ```
2. Familial

   ```
   father mother
   dad mom
   pa ma
   son daughter
   brother sister
   husband wife
   grandfather grandmother
   grandpa grandma
   uncle aunt
   nephew niece
   ```
3. Animal

   ```
   lion lioness
   rooster hen
   stallion mare
   bull cow
   drake duck
   boar sow
   buck doe
   ram ewe
   gander goose
   billy nanny
   ```
4. Royal

   ```
   king queen
   prince princess
   emperor empress
   duke duchess
   marquess marchioness
   earl countess
   baron baroness
   baronet baronetess
   lord lady
   knight dame
   ```
5. Fantastical

   ```
   wizard witch
   giant giantess
   incubus succubus
   nidorino nidorina
   nidoking nidoqueen
   ents entwives
   hanuvoite inimeite
   centaur centaurides
   merman mermaid
   khal khaleesi
   ```

So, for example, you might choose the General and Familial categories. Then any input from `he` to `sir` or `father` to `nephew` would produce a falsy value, and any input from `she` to `madam` or `mother` to `niece` would produce a truthy value.

The values don't all have to be the same truthy/falsy type, e.g. `he` might produce `0` but `sir` might produce `false`. You may assume only the 40 specific lowercase a-z words from your two selected categories are ever input.

**The shortest answer in bytes wins. Tiebreaker is earlier post.**

<sup>(This challenge is not meant to correlate with or make statements about any [current gender-based social issues](https://www.google.com/search?q=gender%20neutrality&tbm=nws).)</sup>

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42206/8478)

Comment: Shouldn't `count` be the masculine of `countess`?

Comment: @mbomb007 [Not necessarily.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl)

Comment: Three answers, all Retina.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 26 bytes (sets 4, 5)

```
[^u]es|ee|m.i|y|^...c|d.*a
```

Retina is @MartinBüttner's regex language. I haven't used anything specific to .NET regexes, so you can test the regex at Regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/rN4nZ3/1). Alternatively you can use Retina's grep `G` mode like so:

```
G`[^u]es|ee|m.i|y|^...c|d.*a
```

and pipe in a file with one word per line for batch testing.

Retina outputs the number of matches by default, giving us our truthy/falsy value. The rule "the values don't all have to be the same truthy/falsy type" is pretty important though since `marchioness` matches twice, giving an output of 2.

<sub>(Using the mod-chaining method from the [previous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42206/distinguish-between-masculine-and-feminine-nouns-in-french-within-100-characters) male/female question seems to be shorter in CJam, but I'll let someone else do that)</sub>

Comment: time is never wasted on a regular expression

Answer (score 3):

## Retina, <s>39</s> 32 bytes (sets 2, 4)

Accounting for `marquess` was annoying, since using `ma` was the best way to get some of the feminines.

```
[^u]es|ma$|mo|y|[mie]e|wi|ter|au
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/rN4nZ3/3)

Thanks to Sp3000 for his golf suggestion.

Comment: [With a little rearranging](https://regex101.com/r/rN4nZ3/3)

Comment: @Sp3000 Ah, thanks. I hadn't noticed I could use `$` for that.

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 28 bytes (sets 3,4)

```
w|[mhorse]e|[^u]es|duc|[dn]y
```

Retina uses .NET regex, but any flavor should work. [Test it at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vK4wB0/1).